# Constructor injection in MVC 3

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have this code in my controller:

```
public class IssueController : BaseController, IIssueController
{

    #region Members

    IPublicationsManagementService publicationService;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

        public IssueController(IPublicationsManagementService publicationService)
        {
            this.publicationService = publicationService;
        }

    #endregion

   public ActionResult IssueSearch()
    {

        return View(new IssueSearchViewModel()
        {
            Magazines
                = new SelectList(publicationService.GetAllProducts(), "Id", "Name")
        });
    }
```

and the injection dependencies  in web config is:

```
<register type="Infoquality.PSMS.Presentation.Web.MVC.Client.Controllers.IIssueController, PSMS.Presentation.Web.MVC.Client"
   mapTo="Infoquality.PSMS.Presentation.Web.MVC.Client.Controllers.IssueController, PSMS.Presentation.Web.MVC.Client">
          <lifetime type="PerWebRequest" />
          <constructor>
            <param name="publicationService">
              <dependency name="sd"/>
            </param>
          </constructor>

 <register type="Infoquality.PSMS.Application.Publications.PublicationsManagement.IPublicationsManagementService, PSMS.Application.Publications"
     mapTo="Infoquality.PSMS.Application.Publications.PublicationsManagement.PublicationsManagementService, PSMS.Application.Publications" 
                  name="sd">
          <lifetime type="singleton" />
        </register>
```

When I run the application the error is :

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [MissingMethodException: No
>   parameterless constructor defined for
>   this object.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor,
>   Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis,
>   Boolean fillCache) +98
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   +67

I need the ASP.NET MVC 3 and razor engine to call the parametrized constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `IDependencyResolver` interface. Once you do this you can use dependency injection anywhere within a MVC 3 application, even views (although property injection only).